# Is there anyway to revert commit to source cod

Tags: html, css, debugging, restore, revert

I'm new to the game ( around 1 month )
I accidentally pressed Start debugging and now my HTML code is messed up like this.

[image]

Is there any solution to revert this. thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

That's called minified css, I don't see html in it but you can use something like [Unminify](https://unminify.com/) or do it by hand to unminify the css.

If you're saying it got rid of your html and put css in it's place, there's something much more wrong than we can tell with just a screenshot.

Comment: hey thanks, i'm glad i had google back up and sync there so i was able to retrieve the previous version. and yea it was the html file then something happened  and it all turned into :D. thanks for the help anyway (y)